# Dúvida sobre struct e lista em c

Tags: c, lista, struct

Estou com problema quando precisa dar um valor a uma pessoa, no caso, preciso dar o valor nome e idade para a pessoa. Eu tentei criar uma `struct PESSOA` e uma lista que contém uma pessoa e um id, porém durante a compilação me apresenta o erro da imagem.

[image: erro]

Segue abaixo meu código:

```
typedef struct PESSOA
{
    char nome[100];
    int idade;
}Pessoa;

typedef struct NO
{
    int id;
    Pessoa pess;
    struct No *prox;
}No;

int main()
{
    int controle;
    int id=0;
    No *no_inicial;
    No *no_proximo;

    no_inicial = (No *)malloc(sizeof(No));
    no_proximo = no_inicial;
    no_proximo->prox = NULL;

    while(1)
    {
        printf("Insira o nome");
        gets(no_proximo->pess().nome);
        printf("Insira a idade");
        scanf("%d", &no_proximo->pess->idade);
        no_proximo->id = id;
}
}
```

Comment: Corrigi a formatação para você.

Answer (score 2):

Assim deve compilar:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct PESSOA {
    char nome[100];
    int idade;
} Pessoa;

typedef struct NO {
    int id;
    Pessoa pess;
    struct NO *prox;
} No;

int main() {
    int controle;
    int id = 0;
    No *no_inicial;
    No *no_proximo;

    no_inicial = (No *) malloc(sizeof(No));
    no_proximo = no_inicial;
    no_proximo->prox = NULL;

    while(1) {
        printf("Insira o nome");
        fgets(no_proximo->pess.nome, 100, stdin);
        printf("Insira a idade");
        scanf("%d", &no_proximo->pess.idade);
        no_proximo->id = id;
    }
}
```

Não sei se esse programa vai fazer o que você quer no entanto.

Algumas observações:

- Nunca, jamais, de forma alguma, ouse pensar na hipótese de utilizar a função `gets`. Esta função é unanimemente odiada e detestada na comunidade de programadores em C por ter sido pessimamente projetada e ser extremamente insegura. No seu código, eu a substitui por uma chamada equivalente, porém segura, de `fgets`.
- Não confunda `No` com `NO`. O nome `No` é o que você deu como apelido para `struct NO`. O nome `NO` isolado nada significa. Não adianta colocar `No` dentro da declaração dos `{ ... }` do próprio `No` porque isso cria um problema do ovo e da galinha: Para que o compilador saiba o que é `No` dentro da estrutura, ele já tem que ter terminado de ler a estrutura. Entretanto, ao usar `struct NO`, o compilador já viu o cabeçalho anteriormente, embora ainda não tenha terminado de ler a estrutura, e portanto não há problema.
- O uso de `a->b` é o mesmo que `(*a).b`. Se o que existe no `a` é um ponteiro para uma estrutura no qual você quer acessar um elemento, use `->`. Se o `a` não é um ponteiro, e use `.`. No caso da sua `No`, ela tem um ponteiro (`prox`) para um outro `No`, e por ser ponteiro, você acessa o conteúdo dele com `->`. Na sua estrutura `No`, também há uma outra estrutura aninhada (`pess`) do tipo `Pessoa` que não é um ponteiro e portanto deve ter seu conteúdo acessado com `.`.
- Só use `()` após um nome se ele representar uma função. O uso de `no_proximo->pess()` só faria sentido se `pess` fosse um ponteiro para função, coisa que iniciantes na linguagem C não vão encontrar tão cedo. Logo, não coloque parênteses após o nome de um campo de alguma `struct` (seja ele acessado por `->` ou por `.`).

Comment: Obrigado, resolveu tudo.

Comment: @ViníciusFrança Neste caso, caso não lhe reste nenhuma dúvida, clique no ✅ que aparece abaixo do número de votação desta resposta para marcá-la como aceita e marcar a sua pergunta como resolvida. Foi um prazer ajudá-lo. 

Answer (score 0):

**Versão Simplificada - Testada**

Crie um arquivo chamado **main.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define EXIT_SUCCESS 0
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    typedef struct{
        char* nome;
        int idade;
    }PESSOA;
    int numPessoas=3;
    int x;
    PESSOA* pessoas = malloc(numPessoas * sizeof *pessoas);
    printf("Insere 3 pessoas\n\r");
    for (x = 0; x < numPessoas; x++){
        pessoas[x].nome=(char*)malloc(sizeof(char*));
        printf("Insira o nome: ");
        scanf("%s",pessoas[x].nome);
        printf("Insira a idade: ");
        scanf("%d",&pessoas[x].idade);
    }
    for (x = 0; x < numPessoas; x++)
        printf("Nome: %s, idade: %d\n",pessoas[x].nome,pessoas[x].idade);
    return (EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

**Compilado e testado com gcc (Linux)**

> ```
> gcc -o main *.c
> ```

**Executado no Linux**

> ```
> ./main
> ```

**Criado com editor**

> ```
> nano
> ```

**Teste feito no Ubuntu 16.04 LTS**